# does professional devops use webmin to manage their server ？

Tags: linux, ubuntu

does professional devops (server administrator) use webmin to manage their server ?

or is it only for unprofessional linux users ?

and is it only for ubuntu(.deb), fedora/redhat(.rpm) ?

thanks !

Comment: I find the conflation of "devops" with "server administrator" disturbing.

Comment: The canonical source of [all DevOps information is Twitter](http://twitter.com/DEVOPS_BORAT).

Answer (score 6):

[Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) can be a handy way to provide a front-end to Linux/Unix tools for inexperienced users (or people looking for a centralized administration interface). I've installed it in cases where I needed to delegate responsibilities to a client or end-user of the system.

An appropriate example would be restarting a daemon or using Webmin to help configure users/groups, printing or Samba shares.

As a professional engineer, I don't use it, but it has its place.

BTW - Webmin has [precompiled binaries for several distributions, as well as a source tarball that can be compiled](http://www.webmin.com/download.html).

Comment: +1 for not being an ass and giving a good answer to the question.